# How to rename and edit an item in a single change request - Azure devops pushes api

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Using the Devops pushes endpoint like `_apis/git/repositories/<Project>/pushes?api-version=6.0` we can [rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#rename-a-file) or [edit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#update-a-file) a file.

This is working no problem. However, I want to rename and edit a file in a single commit. I've tried passing two changes in a single request, like:

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "changeType": "rename",
      "item": {
        "path": "/path/new-filename.txt"
      },
      "sourceServerItem": "/path/old-filename.txt"
    },
    {
      "changeType": "edit",
      "item": {
        "path": "/path/new-filename.txt"
      },
      "newContent": {
        "content": "...new content...",
        "contentType": "rawtext"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This gave the error `"Multiple operations were attempted on file 'path/new-filename.txt' within the same request. Only a single operation may be applied to each file within the same commit. Parameter name: newPush"`

So I tried combining them with the change type of 'all'

```
{
    "changeType": "all",
    "item": {
        "path": "/path/new-filename.txt",
    },
    "sourceServerItem": "/path/old-filename.txt",
    "newContent": {
        "content": "...new content...",
        "contentType": "rawText"
    }
}
```

Still no joy: `"The parameters supplied are not valid. Parameter name: newPush"`

Is this possible, or do I have to separate the changes in two commits?

**Edit:**

Can't even do this with multiple commits in one request . I mean what's the point of [having commits as an array](https://The%20parameters%20are%20incorrect.%20A%20posted%20push%20must%20contain%20exactly%20one%20commit%20and%20one%20refUpdate.%20Parameter%20name:%20newPush) when you must have exactly one commit anyway?

```
The parameters are incorrect. A posted push must contain exactly one commit and one refUpdate.
Parameter name: newPush
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with the Rest API and I can reproduce the same situation.

The issue comes from the limitations of the Rest API itself. When we use the Rest API to do the push action, it limits that you can only make commit once and changes cannot be made to the same file at the same time.

You need to separate the changes in two commits.

To meet your requirement, you can use PowerShell Script to run the Rest API twice to commit the changes.

For example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo}/pushes?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "commitid"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Renaming tasks.md to xxx",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "rename",
          "sourceServerItem": "/path/old-filename.txt",
          "item": {
            "path": "/path/new-filename.txt"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

$newobjectid = $response.commits.commitid

echo $newobjectid

$JSON1 = "
{
  `"refUpdates`": [
    {
      `"name`": `"refs/heads/master`",
      `"oldObjectId`": `"$newobjectid`"
    }
  ],
  `"commits`": [
    {
      `"comment`": `"Renaming tasks.md to xxx`",
      `"changes`": [
        {
          `"changeType`": `"edit`",
          `"item`": {
            `"path`": `"/path/new-filename.txt`"
          },
          `"newContent`": {
            `"content`": `"...new content...`",
            `"contentType`": `"rawtext`"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"
$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON1 -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: this Q was specifically to see if we could rename and edit an item in one request. I don't understand the difficult for the API to implement this.

Comment: I can understand your requirement and reproduce the same situation. So it doesn't support to rename and edit an item in one request for the time being. We can confirm the limit from the error message.  I'm also not sure what the exact limit is. If you want to further investigate the issue, I suggest that you can create a question in DeveloperCommunity:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem

Comment: Currently, we can use PowerShell script as a workaround to execute two commits